# I can't modify a property of an object using a method created inside the same object. I am trying to use foreach then console.log is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, foreach

CODE:

```
    let references = [
        { nombre: 'productA', priceUsd: 2200, qty: 15 },
        { nombre: "productB", priceUsd: 1500, qty: 20 },
        { nombre: "productC", priceUsd: 3000, qty: 7 }
      ];
    const store = {
    products: references,
    increasePrice: function(percToAdd) {
    return this.products.forEach(item =>item['priceUsd']=item.priceUsd*(1+percToAdd/100));}
    }
    const increased = store.increasePrice(30);
    console.log(increased)
```

OUTPUT:

```
undefined
```

But I am looking for something like this:

```
[
{ nombre: 'productA', priceUsd: 2860, qty: 15 },
{ nombre: "productB", priceUsd: 1950, qty: 20 },
{ nombre: "productC", pricesUsd: 3900, qty: 7 }
]
```

I Tried the code outside the method and it works but when I put it inside a function it does not work anymore.

Comment: `forEach` returns `undefined`. Do log the `store` again.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `forEach`  doesnot return value(modify the array) instead perform certain operation on each element of array.

You can use `map` for this case .

```js
let references = [
    { nombre: 'productA', priceUsd: 2200, qty: 15 },
    { nombre: "productB", priceUsd: 1500, qty: 20 },
    { nombre: "productC", priceUsd: 3000, qty: 7 }
];
const store = {
    products: references,
    increasePrice: function (percToAdd) {
        return this.products.map(item => ({ ...item, ["priceUsd"]: item.priceUsd * (1 + percToAdd / 100) }));
    }
}
const increased = store.increasePrice(30);
console.log(increased)
```

Also you have misspelled `priceUsd` in last item of `references`.

Comment: We don't know whether the OP actually wants to clone the objects, in the title of the question he asks for *modifying* them. Please make it clear in your answer that you use an approach that treats the objects as immutable.